# Squid3 trying to add a custom external_acl_type

Tags: squid

I'm trying to create an external acl helper for squid3 to (hopefully) cut down some config lines from my squid3 server and I wrote a simple python script for it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
import time


logger = logging.getLogger( 'squid_auth' )
logger.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
fh = logging.FileHandler( 'spam.log' )
fh.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
formatter = logging.Formatter( '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s' )
fh.setFormatter( formatter )
logger.addHandler( fh )


def grant ():
      sys.stdout.write( 'OK\n' )
      sys.stdout.flush()


def deny ():
      sys.stdout.write( 'ERR\n' )
      sys.stdout.flush()


while True:
      line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
      if line:
              logger.info( line )
              grant()
      else:
              time.sleep( 1 )
```

and added it into my squid.conf:

```
external_acl_type custom_acl %SRC %LOGIN %DST /etc/changemyip/squid/config/acl.py
acl CustomAcl external custom_acl
http_access allow CustomAcl
```

The path to the script is right (I can execute it in shell), the program has execute rights and everything but, when I reload squid I get this error about 5-6 times then squid crashes:

```
Aug 17 14:08:52 server7 (squid): The custom_acl helpers are crashing too rapidly, need help!
Aug 17 14:08:52 server7 squid[28233]: Squid Parent: child process 28290 exited with status 1
Aug 17 14:08:52 server7 squid[28233]: Exiting due to repeated, frequent failures
```

As you can see the script is just printing `OK\n` to the stdout to grant everyone. I haven't even started implementing any logic to it.

Tested with squid version: `3.1.19`

Comment: have you tried without \n (CR/LF) ?

Comment: tried and not working.

Comment: try to remove %LOGIN, just test

Comment: debug_options ALL

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I managed to fix it by changing the ownership of the script to the squid user and moving the file from my home directory to somewhere in the root filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I still had the same problem even after following @tyrells helpful directions.

The fix?

We need to make the python script executable by running the command below.

`sudo chmod u+x /path/to/external-acl.py`

So to summarize here's step by step instructions.

1. Move your script somewhere in the root filesystem. For me it was `/usr/share/acl.py`
2. Fix the permissions. `sudo chown proxy:proxy /usr/share/acl.py`
3. Make the script executable. `sudo chmod u+x /usr/share/acl.py`
4. Restart squid. `sudo service squid restart`